# R convert yy-mm string to date format

Tags: r, date

I have a date field read us a character in data frame that is in short yy-mm format and would like to convert to a date field in R. For example, November 2017 is stored as "17-11".

Now I can convert a date have year, month and day like "17-11-01" using:

```
as.Date("17-11-01", format = "%y-%m-%d")
```

However, when I try to convert just the year and the month as follows

```
as.Date("17-11", format = "%y-%m")
```

R returns 'NA'

Ideas as to why the second example does not work would be appreciated

Note this has been marked as duplicate by Sotos but I'

Comment: Sotos - your suggested 'exact' duplicate answer does not seem to address the issue with a yy-mm format nor does it address the use of as.Date.  I expect I should not need to load the zoo package to solve this - it is probably some syntax issue?